# Why should I call `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` again and again?

Tags: windows, winapi, optimization, gdi

Every example code I have seen are `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` being called again and again. Or `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`.

But I think drawing on the screen happens very frequently (especially in a game), so storing the drawing in memory is better than getting and releasing device contexts all time.

So I went the route of getting a DC and "keeping it", only releasing it when the program ends. But why don't people do it like this? Is it because `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` cost very little?

```c
case WM_CREATE:
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd); //hdc is declared as global HDC
    MyBitmap = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
    return 0;
case WM_PAINT:
    MemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    OldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(MemDC, MyBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 300, 300, MemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(MemDC, OldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(MemDC);
    return 0;
```

Comment: *"But why people doesn't do like this?"* - Because it's all wrong. So you saved the cheap operation `GetDC` only to call the expensive one on each redraw (`CreateCompatibleDC`). And since you never call `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint`, the invalid region never gets validated, causing continuous `WM_PAINT` messages being generated, even when there's nothing to draw. You need to learn how this works before trying to optimize.

Comment: People don't do it like this because the documentation says that you can't. DCs should not be cached like this, unless you take special care to create your window class with the appropriate flags, which you should not do. DCs are meant to be temporary objects, created only when necessary and disposed immediately afterwards. Retrieval of a DC with `GetDC` is cheap enough that this worked well on 286 processors. It is *guaranteed* to be fast enough on whatever silicon you're running now.

Comment: @CodyGray Wow my curiosity just blown away! Thanks everyone for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you presented here is wrong. First off, you need to read a little more of the documentation. Here is a useful link: [**Painting and Drawing**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162759(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically there are two ways to update a window:

- In response to the `WM_PAINT` message. Use the `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` functions to paint the client area properly. This message is sent by the system when a part of the client area is "invalidated" (as a result of resizing, restoring from minimized state, moving a window previously obscured, or programmatically invalidating it.) `WM_PAINT` is a low-priority message, received just before the message-queue gets empty.
- Specifically drawing a part or the whole client area without having an invalidated region on it. Use `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` for this. Useful if you want to make changes immediately visible, when the application (CPU) is busy.

Writing some code to process the `WM_PAINT` message is normally almost mandatory, while specifically drawing as well is optional, depending on the requirements of your application.

Never send or post a `WM_PAINT` message yourself, instead invalidate a part or the client area - the application will receive a `WM_PAINT` message before becoming idle. If you want the painting to occur immediately call `UpdateWindow` - this bypasses the message queue.

Answer (score 1):

A recent (Aug 2016) security update in Windows 10 prevents the reuse of printer device contexts. After printing one document Windows 10 will refuse to print again with that same DC. It has always been a preferred practice to create a new DC for each document, but now it seems to be a requirement in Windows 10.