# MFC Redraw window in paint application problem

Tags: c++, mfc, paint, invalidation, redraw

I'm trying to write Paint on MFC but I have a problem with redrawing window while draw new figures, move or resize existing ones. When I use `Invalidate()` or `InvalidateRect(NULL)` after every mouse move it is good but after adding 3-4 figures application crashes because it can't redraw all window in time. I've tried `InvalidateRect(FigureRect)` and `RedrawWindow(FigureRect)` but it doesn't work correctly (smears appear).

That works good but app crashes:

```
void CGraphicsEditorView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    ...
    if (m_mouseDrugging && m_cursorInside)
    {
        m_figureSelected->Move(point);
        Invalidate();
    }
    ...
    CView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

This is my `OnDraw` function:

```
void CGraphicsEditorView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    for (Figure* figure : figures)
        figure->Draw(pDC);
}
```

Figure is an abstract class from which are inherited Rectangle, Ellipse and Triangle classes.

For example, `Draw` function for Rectangle:

```
void CRectangle::Draw(CDC* pDC) {
    pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);

    CPen penBorder(penType, penWidth, borderColor);
    CBrush* br = (brushType == HS_TRANSPARENT) ? nullptr : new CBrush(brushType, fillColor);
    pDC->SelectObject(&penBorder);
    pDC->SelectObject(br);

    pDC->Rectangle(bound);
}
```

Do I redraw the window correctly?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: So long as all the elements of 'figures' are valid I don't immediately see something that would cause a crash, however you don't show nearly enough to make a full determination of that. For example, run this in the debugger and see where the crash is actually happening (you may need to go up the stack to find the part of your code that calls into a library but it's almost certainly a problem with your code and not the library in question).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Figures are rectangles, ellipses and triangles only. I show you almost all of the code except the move and draw functions. Figures are drawn by coordinates of its bounding box represented as rectangles. Move is simple change in figure's bounding box coordinates.

Comment: As above said: Run in debugger and see *exactly* the place where crash occurs. From your code here it's absolutely not obviously. Or, at least, post full `figure->Draw(pDC);` method here.

Comment: I show full Draw function for Rectangle. For other figures it's the same only in an Ellipse, an ellipse function is called and in a triangle a polygon function.

Comment: `new CBrush` is both a memory leak and resource leak. Your program will crash when you hit 10,000 GDI resource leaks.

Comment: OMG, I also noticed it right now. Deleting brush fix my problem!) But I don't understand why did it crash? Memory used by app is 4-5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating causes `WM_PAINT` to be sent, and these are processed somehow "asynchronously", as `WM_PAINT` (`OnDraw()`)is a low-priority message (processed just before the message-queue is emptied). This can also cause "flickering". As mouse-move is a message sent many times as you move the mouse, you should rather not invalidate the window and better not perform lengthy/CPU-costly operations in there. Instead, I would consider a combination of painting and drawing. Details in the links below (related questions I have answered in the past):

[Some controls are not drawing, seemingly at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024993/some-controls-are-not-drawing-seemingly-at-random/56050188#56050188)

[MFC window graphic is gone after minimizing/maximizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287210/mfc-window-graphic-is-gone-after-minimizing-maximizing/55290554#55290554)

[Paint invalid areas of a window using Win32 API and GDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825479/paint-invalid-areas-of-a-window-using-win32-api-and-gdi/43876162#43876162)

[Win32API) Why should I GetDC and ReleaseDC again and again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316141/win32api-why-should-i-getdc-and-releasedc-again-and-again/39317316#39317316)

As for the crashes, they are no-doubt a result of implementation errors - the "asynchronous" nature of `WM_PAINT` message-processing may have sth to do here, eg some variables may have been changed (in `OnMouseMove()`), and when they are finally accessed in `OnDraw()` some data may be inconsistent.

Comment: I added `OnPaint()` function to response `ON_WM_PAINT()` and call `OnDraw(CDC*)` function from it. But I don't undersand how to call window redraw if I remove all `Invalidate()` calls.

Comment: You can perform custom "drawing" (not through `Invalidate()/OnDraw()`) at any point in your application using the `GetDC()/ReleaseDC()` functions, instead of the `BeginPaint()/EndPaint()` ones, which is called "painting" and is what `OnDraw()` does. Drawing is executed directly. Check my posts, it is described in much more detail.