# CChildView::OnPaint() Refresh Slowing When Painting Many Data Points

Tags: windows, visual-c++, graphics, mfc

I am writing an MFC Windows App to plot the motion of a wheeled robot.
In `CChildView::OnPaint()` I do a `pdc->FillRect(ViewRect, &CBrush( RGB(128,128,128) ) );`

Then I use `pdc->MoveTo` and `pdc->LineTo` to draw all the data points etc. refreshed every 250ms.

Problem is as the robot progresses on its travels the number of data points increases to a level where the `OnPaint()` function refresh time becomes noticeable.

In a previous DOS app I did years ago I got around this sluggish refresh rate by removing the fill background paint and replaced it with a plot all the data points in the background colour, then painting them all again in there foreground item colour. Thus reducing the number of changed pixels.

Would this method be valid for what I am doing in MFC `OnPaint()` or is there a better solution please?

Comment: It's not clear why you're erasing the background at all.

Comment: Because the foreground changes every 250ms. Hence do an onpaint to clear the view area ( FillRect ) then draw the object I want over the top of the new canvas,

Comment: Are you using a memory DC to do the rendering and then blitting it to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Painting in a DOS applications is simple, because you have full control of the process and you don't get paint requests from the system - normally you have to introduce delays if you want to achieve a "motion" effect. In Windows though painting is very different, because you may (or may not) receive paint requests from the system, if the user minimizes/maximizes/restores,  moves, unhides etc or programmatically invalidates a window. This causes an "invalid" area on the window surface. If the window contains an invalid area it will receive a [**`WM_PAINT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message. It is a low-priority message, posted just before the application is about to enter the idle state, also it is in some way "asynchronous", posted when the system decides so.

First you need to fully understand the invalidating/painting mechanism in Windows. The documentation you must read is: [**Painting and Drawing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I have posted quite a bit about this, please check my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938927/mfc-redraw-window-in-paint-application-problem/57941957)** (and the links in the post).

As for your question, I would suggest using a combination of painting and drawing. Many suggest not painting outside the `WM_PAINT` message (`OnPaint()`/`OnDraw()` in MFC), but this is not suitable for all cases, as the message is sent asynchronously, and it's also very hard to implement a really optimized operation, painting only the affected area; you would actually have to paint the invalidated area as well. It is best used to paint the whole client area of the window. You could definitely use it in your app (and it's logically "correct"), but as you have found it's really "wasteful", and has a sluggish and choppy feel. So my proposal is:

- Use Painting to paint the entire client area, in response to WM_PAINT messages. Better use `OnDraw()`, rather than `OnPaint()` for a `CView/CScrollView`-derived class. It should paint the background, if any, all additoinal objects (labels, axes etc) and finally all data points.
- Use Drawing (`GetDC()`/`ReleaseDC()`) to paint only the section that changes, ie a single data point at a time. You will have to create a new worker thread (so as to not block the main/UI thread). It must do the calculations, add the new data point to some list-of-data-points (also used by the UI thread in `OnDraw()` to paint the whole window) and draw the new data point only. You should use some sort of synchronization (eg Critical Section) to access the data points list, because it is used and modified by more than one threads. As all paint operations should best be performed in the context of the UI thread, you can define a custom message and have the worker thread sending this message (`SendMessage()`) to the window. The routine handling the message should do the actual drawing, ie paint the new data point.

If implemented correctly this should result in a smooth operation, allowing the window to be moved or resized while the paint operation is in progress, without blocking the window or the application.

Comment: Hello and many thanks to all for the posts.
Reply reading and bit more research and I have successfully implemented

pdc.CreateCompatibleDC( &Thisdc );
bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap( &Thisdc , ViewRect.Width(), ViewRect.Height());
Etc. Etc

I have added so far in my testing map over 1000 moveto's and lineto's and the flicker is a thing of the past,

Comment: @Constantine: What if your incoming data is still faster than the drawing part? Too many Sendmessage(s) will IIRC "saturate" the UI thread.

Comment: @TomTom, my suggestion is based on the assumption that the drawing of a single data point is fairly fast, and more specifically faster than the rate the data are generated or arrive. The idea is very simple, draw only the part that changes, not the whole screen, if not necessary. If the display system cannot cope (even with these greatly reduced requirements), it is not possible to have a different drawing for every single data-point, even theoretically. In such cases one possible solution could be periodic updates - an update may be drawing more than one data-points.